# Context free grammar to NFA

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, finite-automata

I've been given an exercise to solve which goes as follows: generate an NFA from the given CFG,
S -> AB | c
A -> aAb | c
B -> bBa | c

Now correct me if I'm wrong, but if this language has an NFA it means it is regular. but looking at this grammar the language described is - L={w| w=a<sup>n</sup>cb<sup>n+k</sup>ca<sup>k</sup>} Assuming I'm not wrong I can use the pumping lemma -> by taking the promised number n, choose the word a<sup>n</sup>cb<sup>n+k</sup>ca<sup>k</sup>, for xyz we get x=a<sup>s</sup> y=a<sup>t</sup> while t>=1, then I can pump for i=2 and get a<sup>n+t</sup>cb<sup>n+k</sup>ca<sup>k</sup> which is not in the language hence the language is not regular and that means there cant be an NFA for it.

I might have done something wrong but I cant see it, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your set-theoretic characterization of the grammar you've been given.
I also agree with the statement that $L$ is not regular. The [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) can be [used to reason](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/reg-lang/Myhill-Nerode/) about it as follows:
$L$ has infinitely many equivalence classes under the Myhill-Nerode theorem, so it's not regular.
Specifically, each $a^n$ is distinct from every $a^m$ where $n \ne m$. This can be shown by observing for the distinguisher $cb^{n+k}ca^{k}$, $a^{n}cb^{n+k}ca^{k}$ is in $L$, but $a^{m}cb^{n+k}ca^{k}$ is not.